# How does this pointer typecasting work?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

Can anyone please explain how the following code works? I wish to know what is exactly the value returned to variable p and how?

```
#define MR 3
#define MC 4
int (*p)[MC];
p=(int(*)[MC])malloc(MR*sizeof(*p));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this question going to help others in the future? For that matter, frankly, how is it going to help _you_?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From top to bottom (noting `MC 4` and `MR 3`)

```
int (*p)[MC];
```

declares `p` as a pointer to an array of 4 `int`.

```
sizeof(*p)
```

size of an array of 4 `int`

```
MR*sizeof(*p)
```

3 * (size of an array of 4 `int`), i.e. **12** contiguous `int` values.

Finally, the cast:

```
p=(int(*)[MC])malloc(MR*sizeof(*p));
```

is simply forcing the underlying `void*` returned by `malloc` tothe pointer-type that of the lvalue of the assignment, the pointer `p`.

In the end, this **dynamically** allocates an array (dim=3) of arrays (dim=4) of `int`, in a single dynamic contiguous block of memory. Were this allocated as an automatic variable it would be equivalent to:

```
int p[MR][MC]
```

And since you asked how it works. poorly. This is C++. It should be done as:

```
std::vector<std::array<int,MC>> ar(MR);
```

Comment: Why a `vector`? The array dimensions are fixed-length, so shouldn't it be `std::array<std::array<int, MC>, MR> ar;` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau shooting for the same dynamic allocation concept.

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a variable of type "pointer to int array of size `MC`". `sizeof(*p)` is the size of `MC` ints. Effectively, `p` is now the pointer to a 2D array with `MR` rows and `MC` columns.

Comment: Can you please explain how?